# Badge notifications do not open on Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I click either of the "electorate" or "java" badges and just end up where I started if I click the "Open with Stack Exchange" option.
[image]

Comment: Bonus bug: I'm unable to open this on my Android device moments after posting it - "Question may have been deleted."

Comment: What if you open it with Chrome/browser? AFAIK, badge which is not coming from specific post (e.g. Electorate) is not handled by the app yet. As for the bonus bug, its a known issue due to race condition between SE database synchronization.

Comment: Using Chrome it takes me to my profile page (if I'm logged in) or redirects to the home page (if I'm not logged in).